# FFmpeg scale pad with watermark error parsing filterchain

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I'm trying to scale a landscape video to full screen ratio with black pad around and add a watermark above, running this command :

```
-i videoInput.MP4 
-i  watermark-.jpg 
-filter_complex 
[0:v]scale=720.0:720.0*0.59,pad=720.0:720.0*1.77:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black[main][1:v]scale=iw*0.56:-1[v1];[main][v1]overlay=0:0 
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy -preset ultrafast -y output.mp4
```

And then I'm getting this error :

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2825f38a0] Trailing garbage after a filter: scale=iw*0.56:-1[v1];[main][v1]overlay=0:0

[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2825f38a0] Error parsing filterchain '[0:v]scale=720.0:720.0*0.59,pad=720.0:720.0*1.77:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black[main][1:v]scale=iw*0.56:-1[v1];[main][v1]overlay=0:0' 

around: scale=iw*0.56:-1[v1];[main][v1]overlay=0:0

Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I'm not able to found the error around the filter graph.

Is the filter graph incorrect ? How to fix it ?

Comment: `...black[main];[1:v]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon after the pad filter. It should be

```
pad=720.0:720.0*1.77:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:black[main];
```